# Cakephp 3 Update query

Tags: cakephp-3.0

How to update data in cakephp 3?

Comment: First check the CakePHP 3 docs on [how to update data](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#updating-data) before you asked a question here. I think this is more laziness.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this,

```
$tablename = TableRegistry::get("Model");
$query = $tablename->query();
            $result = $query->update()
                    ->set(['fieldname' => 'value'])
                    ->where(['condition' => 'value'])
                    ->execute();
```

Comment: Be aware this is not the default way of updating data. This does not trigger events like Model.afterSave.

Answer (score 3):

You can use another methods such:

```
$tablename = TableRegistry::get("Model");
$conditions = array('id'=>12);
$fields = array('name'=>'andro','family'=>'lpoez');
$tablename->updateAll($fields, $conditions);
```

Comment: Reference https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html section bulk updates

Answer (score 0):

```
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

$articlesTable = TableRegistry::get('Articles');
$article = $articlesTable->get(12); // Return article with id 12

$article->title = 'CakePHP is THE best PHP framework!';
$articlesTable->save($article);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. A good answer to a question should include more than just code, there should be a description of what you are doing and why you believe it is the correct answer. Also, please heck the formatting guide in the answer editor to see how to properly post code.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create/update join table information when using newEntity() or patchEntity(). Your POST data should look like:

// For add New Record,

```
$table = $this->Table->newEntity();

if($this->request->is(['post'])){
   $post_data = $this->request->data;
   $table = $this->Tags->patchEntity($table, $post_data);
   $this->Table->save($table);  //save record
}
```

// For Update Record

```
$table = $this->Table->get($id); //get data using id

if ($this->request->is(['post'])) {
   $post_data = $this->request->data;
   $table = $this->Tags->patchEntity($table, $post_data);
   $this->Table->save($table);  //update record
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating your data is equally easy, and the save() method is also used for that purpose:

```
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

$articlesTable = TableRegistry::get('Articles');
$article = $articlesTable->get($id); // Return article with id = $id (primary_key of row which need to get updated)

$article->title = 'CakePHP is THE best PHP framework!';
// other fields if necessary
 ..........
$articlesTable->save($article);
```

[CookBook official Documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#updating-data)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of updating data.

You can get the existing entity and the change values and update:
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#updating-data

```
$entity = TableRegistry::get('Users')->get(1);
$entity->name = 'foo';
TableRegistry::get('Users')->save($entity);
```

You can patch an entity with an array for instance request data:
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#merging-request-data-into-entities

```
$entity = TableRegistry::get('Users')->get(1);
TableRegistry::get('Users')->patchEntity($entity, $this->request>getData);
TableRegistry::get('Users')->save($entity);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is creating a edit function. You can use Postman or another tool to manipulate de data. So you put the fields you want modify in the body of the postman using the Put method and the id in url. 
The code is some like this:

```
 public function edit($id)
{
    $result = NULL;
       $this->request->allowMethod(['put']);
        if ($this->request->is(['put'])) {
           $data = $this->request->getData();
           $result = $this->Articles->get($id);
           if($result) {
              $result = $this->Articles->patchEntity($result, $data);
              $status = $this->Articles->save($result);
              if ($status) {
                    $status = true;
                    $this->setResponse($this->response->withStatus(200));
                    $result = ['new_data' => $result];
              } else {
                  $this->setResponse($this->response->withStatus(400));
                  $result = $data;
              }
           } else {
              $this->setResponse($this->response->withStatus(404));
              $result = $data;
           }            
        } 
        return $result;
}
```

OBS: To use that you need generate the MVC skeleton with a bake command in the table.

Answer (score 0):

with relationships hasOne: table-A hasOne table-B , u can do like this:

*In Controller of table-A:

```
$ralationTable = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('table-B');

$data = $ralationTable ->newEntity();

$data->field1 = 'something';

$data->field1 = 'something';  

$this->table-A->table-B->save($data);
```